# ByteUnit class to convert across size units

Tags: java, converting, enum

Based on [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class I wrote similar class to convert size units:

```
public enum ByteUnit {

  BYTES("B") {
    @Override
    public long toBytes(long value) {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long toKiB(long value) {
      return value / KIBI;
    }

    @Override
    public long toMiB(long value) {
      return value / MIBI;
    }

    @Override
    public long toGiB(long value) {
      return value / GIBI;
    }

    @Override
    public long convert(long value, @NotNull ByteUnit unit) {
      return unit.toBytes(value);
    }
  },

  KIBIBYTES("KiB") {
    @Override
    public long toBytes(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, KIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toKiB(long value) {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long toMiB(long value) {
      return value / (MIBI / KIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toGiB(long value) {
      return value / (GIBI / KIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long convert(long value, @NotNull ByteUnit unit) {
      return unit.toKiB(value);
    }
  },

  MEBIBYTES("MiB") {
    @Override
    public long toBytes(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, MIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toKiB(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, MIBI / KIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toMiB(long value) {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long toGiB(long value) {
      return value / (GIBI / MIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long convert(long value, @NotNull ByteUnit unit) {
      return unit.toMiB(value);
    }
  },

  GIBIBYTES("GiB") {
    @Override
    public long toBytes(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, GIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toKiB(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, GIBI / KIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toMiB(long value) {
      return safeTo(value, GIBI / MIBI);
    }

    @Override
    public long toGiB(long value) {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long convert(long value, @NotNull ByteUnit unit) {
      return unit.toGiB(value);
    }
  };

  private static final long KIBI = 1024L;
  private static final long MIBI = KIBI * 1024L;
  private static final long GIBI = MIBI * 1024L;

  @NotNull
  private final String name;

  private ByteUnit(@NotNull String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public abstract long convert(long sourceValue, @NotNull ByteUnit sourceUnit);

  public abstract long toBytes(long value);

  public abstract long toKiB(long value);

  public abstract long toMiB(long value);

  public abstract long toGiB(long value);

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  private static long safeTo(long value, long multiplier) {
    final long overflow = Long.MAX_VALUE / multiplier;
    if (value > overflow) {
      return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    if (value < -overflow) {
      return Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    return value * multiplier;
  }
}
```

But I don't realy like the design. I think there are two ways to improve it:

1. Use "from" instead of "to". Main disadvantage is that it differs from TimeUnit style. Usage will look like:

   ```
   ByteUnit.KIBIBYTES.fromMiB(42)
   ```
2. Create intermediate object of class, which has all the methods of converting (leads to excess allocation on each call):

   ```
   ByteUnit.mebibytes(42).toBytes()
   ```

Have anyone any suggestions?